# Fetch response isn't getting saved in session storage every time

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I'm building my first big app. I'm trying to save the url of a photo I saved in Firebase storage fetched to frontend, but the response won't be saved to session storage all the time. It seems to me that the program is saving it randomly(sometimes it works and sometimes not, and I can't find a pattern) and I don't understand why. I tested the backend with Postman, and it's working fine, I get the expected result all the time, but the problem is on the Javascript side. Any idea why?

P.S Sorry for my bad english, I'm not a native speaker.

```
document.querySelector('#fileUpload').addEventListener('change', event => {
  handleImageUpload(event)
})


const handleImageUpload = event => {
  const files = event.target.files
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('file', files[0])

  fetch('http://localhost:8080/profile/pic/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(resp => sessionStorage.setItem('image_path', JSON.stringify(resp.response)))
}
```

[Backend response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM34T.png)

Comment: You say it's not getting saved every time, meaning it gets saved some times. And the code also looks ok. Thus, maybe an error occurred in the backend. Check the logs both on backend, and the devtools in the browser to see if the response is 'ok'.

Comment: Maybe add a `catch()` to the `fetch` like it is done in [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file). So that you can see, when there is an error.

Comment: the thing is, it is woking as expected, I keep on testing it with Postman and it returns the correct value all the time. I don't see any problem either, and the image is uploaded to firebase, but when I try to save it to session storage it won't work sometimes. It's very strange.

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment there can be an issue with the API, try adding a catch block to see if the API is failing.

 .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });

Comment: Found the problem, I needed to add Acces-Control-Allow-Origin, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, the fetch failed because I didn't have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).